# How do I append an array to another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two sequential (non-associative) arrays whose values I want to combine into a new array, ignoring the index but preserving the order. Is there a better solution (i.e. an existing operator or function) other than do the following:

```
$a = array('one', 'two');
$b = array('three', 'four', 'five');

foreach($b as $value) {
    $a[] = $value;
}
```

Remark: The '+' operator doesn't work here ('three' with index 0 overwrites 'one' with index zero). <strike>The function array_merge has the same problem</strike>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_merge` is what you want, and I don't think you are correct with that overwriting problem. From the manual:

> If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 3):

[`$a + $b` on two arrays](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) is the union of `$a` and `$b`:

> The + operator appends elements of remaining keys from the right handed array to the left handed, whereas duplicated keys are NOT overwritten.

So use [`array_merge`](http://docs.php.net/array_merge) to merge both arrays:

```
$merged = array_merge($a, $b);
```